# TypeError when concatonate two matrix: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have this two fuctions:

## Creates an indentity matrix

```
def m_ident(m):
  for i in range(0,m.shape[0]):
     for j in range(0,m.shape[1]):
        if i == j:
            m[i,j] = 1
        else:
            m[i,j] = 0
  return m 


def inverted_matrix(m):
   if numpy.linalg.det(m) == 0:
     return False
   x = numpy.concatenate(m,m_ident(m))
   return x
```

When I run the last fucntion to concatonate the 2 matrix it shows the error:

```
File "C:/Users/JJ/OneDrive - ISCTE-IUL/EDA/Aula1.py", line 139, in inverted_matrix
x = numpy.concatenate(m,m_ident(m))
```

File "<**array_function** internals>", line 6, in concatenate
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: The 2nd argument to `concatenate` is the `axis`, a number, not another array.  Keep the `numpy` reference handy.  Checking your arguments against the function docs should be your first debugging step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a list/sequence as first argument to [np.concatenate](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html), while the second parameter is the axis along which the arrays will be concatenated. Therefore you just need to change the code as:

```py
def inverted_matrix(m):
   if np.linalg.det(m) == 0:
     return False
   x = np.concatenate([m,m_ident(m)])
   return x
```

However, notice that `m_ident` is changing `m` itself rather than creating a new matrix, and therefore you will get two identity matrices concatenated.

To avoid that you can do:

```
def m_ident(m):
    I = np.zeros(m.shape)
    for i in range(0,m.shape[0]):
       for j in range(0,m.shape[1]):
          if i == j:
             I[i,j] = 1
    return I
```

or even better use [np.identity](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.identity.html).

Comment: Thanks, I have some questions question. First when you do  I = np.zeros(m.shape), what does m.shape? Does it give us the number of lines and columns of a matrix at the sametime? And the matrix m is only changing because I do return m and it stores the new matrix?   @FBruzzesi

Comment: Yes, it is the same of doing `I = np.zeros( (m.shape[0], m.shape[1]))`. Since `m.shape` is already a tuple you can pass it in such a way. Even better, you could use [np.zeros_like](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros_like.html#numpy.zeros_like) as `np.zeros_like(m)` which has exacly the purpuse of creating a array of zeros of the same shape of the given array.